# Show a pretty timestamp with month name

Tags: java, timestamp

I have a [`Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Timestamp.html) object, and I want to show it.

Actually, I'm using `new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()).toLocaleString()`, and I have this result:

> 27 déc. 2021 17:54:35

But :

- the `toLocaleString()` method is deprecated
- It return the value according to computer's lang, so it can show this :

> Dec 27, 2021 17:54:35 PM

Which is NOT what I want. In my personnal computer, in french, it's fine. But, on VPS it's not fine.

Also, all finded thread are only talking about formatting but without month name, which is not what I want.

How can I easily show the timestamp, in French language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

Use new conversion methods added to the old class [`Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Timestamp.html) to convert to modern *java.time* classes.

```java
Timestamp myTimestamp = Timestamp.from( Instant.now() );  // Simulate receiving a `Timestamp` object from old code not yet updated to *java.time*. 
System.out.println(
        myTimestamp
                .toInstant()                              // Convert from legacy class to modern class.
                .atZone(                                  // Adjust into a time zone.
                        ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" )
                )                                         // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object. 
                .format(
                        DateTimeFormatter
                                .ofLocalizedDateTime(
                                        FormatStyle.FULL
                                )
                                .withLocale(
                                        Locale.FRANCE
                                )
                )                                          // Returns a `String` object, generated text.
);
```

See this code [run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/bkb0Z2).

> mardi 28 décembre 2021 à 05:39:58 heure normale du Japon

## Details

`Timestamp` is one of the terrible legacy date-time classes. These classes were years ago [supplanted by the modern *java.time*](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) classes. Never use Timestamp, Date, Calendar, SimpleDateFormat, etc.

Capture the current moment as seen in UTC, with an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

Capture the current moment as seen in a particular time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

Generate text in an automatically localized format. Specify a locale to determine the human language used in translation and the cultural norms used in abbreviation, capitalization, order of elements, and such.

```
Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.MEDIUM ).withLocale( locale ) ;
String output = zdt.format( f ) ;
```

If receiving a moment from a database column of a data type akin to the SQL standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, use `OffsetDateTime` class in Java with a JDBC driver compliant with JDBC 4.2 or later.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

Adjust into your desired time zone to yield a `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
```

All of this has been handled many times already on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.

Comment: I should use `Timestamp` because I'm getting informations from databases. So, I just will use `timestamp.toInstant()`. Also, the "ZoneOf" method don't exist

Comment: @Elikill58 Nope, no need to ever use `Timestamp` class. See my edits.

Comment: I see and I will check, thanks ! And if it was already handled on SO, just flag as duplicate instead of answering