# Timestamp calculate time left

Tags: java

I need to calculate the remaining time of a timestamp and the current time, i create the timestamp using

```
new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis() + (3600000 * 6)); // +6 hours from now
```

then i compare the times using

```
DateFormatUtils.format(System.currentTimeMillis() - timeStamp.getTime(), "HH:mm");
```

the problem that this gives 16h:00m, it should be 6 hours or less.

Comment: There are 3,600,000 milliseconds in an hour.

Comment: @shmosel sorry edited the question, 3600000, still gives same output

Comment: `System.currentTimeMillis() - timeStamp.getTime()` will be negative.... not what you intended, right?  If `16:00` is a typo for `18:00`...

Comment: @JimGarrison now using DateFormatUtils.format(timeStamp.getTime()-System.currentTimeMillis(), "HH:mm:ss") gives me 03:00:00

Comment: By the way… Representing elapsed time using “HH:mm” clock-time is inherently ambiguous. Consider using [standard ISO 8601 format](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the name would suggest, `DateFormatUtils` is for formatting dates. What you want is `DurationFormatUtils`. And your calculation is backwards:

```
long duration = timeStamp.getTime() - System.currentTimeMillis();
String formatted = DurationFormatUtils.formatDuration(duration, "HH:mm");
```

Answer (score 1):

> new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis() + (3600000 * 6)); // +6 hours from now

Never use `Timestamp` class, as discussed in [another Answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70498935/642706) today. The legacy date-time classes were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

That line should be:

```
Instant then = Instant.now().plus( Duration.ofHours( 6 ) ) ;
```

Determine elapsed time using `Duration` class.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( Instant.now() , then ) ;
```

Compare number of hours.

```
if( d.toHours() > 6 ) { … }
```

Extract parts.

```
String result = d.toHoursPart() + “h “ + d.toMinutesPart() + "m " ;
```